# Importing error in python3.6

Tags: python

[image]

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_jwt import JWT, jwt_required
from .security import authenticate, identity


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "jose"
api = Api(app)  # Can easily add resources to this "app"

jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)

items = []

# every resource has to be a class
class Item(Resource):
    @jwt_required()
    def get(self, name):

        item = next(filter(lambda x: x["name"] == name, items), None)

        return {"item": item}, 200 if item else 404

    def post(self, name):

        if next(filter(lambda x: x["name"] == name, items), None) is not None:
            return {"Message": "An Item with the name {} already exit".format(name)}, 400

        data = request.get_json()

        item = {"name": name, "price": data["price"]}
        items.append(item)
        return item, 201 # 201 is status code for created


class ItemList(Resource):

    def get(self):
        return {"items": items}



api.add_resource(Item, "/item/<string:name>")
api.add_resource(ItemList, "/items")

app.run(port=5000, debug=True)


from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp
from .user import User

users = [
    User(1, "bob", "asdf")
]

username_mapping = {u.username: u for u in users}

userid_mapping = {u.id: u for u in users}


def authenticate(username, password):
    user = username_mapping.get(username, None)
    if user and safe_str_cmp(user.password, password):

        return user


def identity(payload):
    user_id = payload["identity"]
    return userid_mapping.get(user_id, None)
```

I am trying to import authenticate and identity into my app.py from security.py. They are both in the same directory.

The linter is not giving me any errors but when i Run app.py it gives me this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.security'; '**main**' is not a package

I am not sure where this is coming from. Is it not recognizing security.py exist with in the same directory?

Comment: Can you put current directory list in question, so we can have insight in folder/files structure?

Comment: Yes, I provided a screenshot of my folder setup

Comment: what's the full stack trace of that import error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/moisesmiguelhernandez/Desktop/Docs/flask-application/section4/code/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .security import authenticate, identity
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.security'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: try `from security import authenticate, identity`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem seemed to be that python was not getting to the right folder.
My code was in a folder called *Code* and Code was inside my root folder *Section4* in my root folder is also the venv folder. I ended up moving my files from *Code* to *Section4*. I ran app.py and it started to run the app smoothly again.